# Smooth scroll the ID issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling, hashtag

I am working on a site and have a "Features" link in my navigation bar. When on the homepage, if "Features" is clicked, I have it scroll down to an **H1** with the id="expo-features" (simplified here):

```
<div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="#expo-features">Features</a>
      <a href="register.php">Registration</a>
      <a href="booth.php">Reserve A Booth</a>
      <a href="sponsor.php">Sponsor Event</a>
      <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</div>

/*Scrolls to this section*/

<h1 id="expo-features">Expo Features</h1>
```

I added some script in the head to make this work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

That all works great! It scrolls perfectly to the expo-features id. Of course, since this is in my navigation, it is appearing on other pages. So I need it to be able to link to the same section (obviously it won't scroll to it, since it's going to a different page – but that's okay). On some of my pages, that works.

However, I have 2 pages that have their own unique id# links with the same script in the head. But the "Features" button that is sitting up in the nav now doesn't jump on those 2 pages. I can't figure out why?

---

Long story short: [here is my website](https://virtualdigitalexpo.com)

- "Features" button in nav id# links to section on homepage
- That works on homepage, register page, and contact page
- "Features" button doesn't work on [booth page](https://virtualdigitalexpo.com/booth.php) and [sponsor page](https://virtualdigitalexpo.com/sponsor.php) and I think it's because those pages have their own unique id# links with the same script in the head.
- And yes, on the other pages, the "Features" button href="https://virtualdigitalexpo.com/#expo-features"

Comment: You know you could've done that by [one line of css code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1)

Comment: if you check your browser's console you'll see this error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined*, and when you go to the error line you'll see it's this one `scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top` which means `$(hash).offset()` is undefined, which means `if (this.hash !== "")` is not working as well as you think it is, try not only checking for `""`, but also for stuff like `null` and `undefined` and try to pinpoint the cause of why `this.hash` is not getting a proper value

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are only checking if the anchor has a `hash` set in its `href`,  while you need to also check if the anchor actually points to the current document.

This can be easily achieved by building the path of your anchor without the hash:

```
// builds an URL path without the hash
function buildPath( url ) {
  return url.origin + url.pathname + url.search;
}
```

and comparing it with the one of your document. Note that you **can not** use `window.location` because your HTML anchors will not use this as their *baseURI*, but the `document.baseURI` value, which can be modified, e.g by a `<base>` element.
So we need to build a new URL instance from that base URI:

```
const doc_URI = new URL( document.baseURI );
```

And we're good to go:

```js
document.onclick = (evt) => {
  const target = evt.target;
  if( target.matches( 'a' ) ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const doc_URI = new URL( document.baseURI );
    const is_valid_anchor = target.hash !== "" &&
      buildPath( target ) === buildPath( doc_URI );
    console.log( 'is valid', is_valid_anchor );
  }
};
// builds an URL path without the hash
function buildPath( url ) {
  return url.origin + url.pathname + url.search;
}
```

```css
a { display: block; }
```

```html
<a href="#foo">"#foo" (same)</a>
<a href="/some-other-page/#foo">"/some-other-page/#foo" (different)</a>
<a href="?bar=baz#foo">"?bar=baz#foo" (different)</a>
<a href="">"" (different)</a>
<a href="https://stacksnippets.net/js#foo">"https://stacksnippets.net/js#foo" (same)</a>
<a href="http://stacksnippets.net/js#foo">"http://stacksnippets.net/js#foo" (different)</a>
```

So in your code that would give

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

  // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
  // And that it points to the current document
  var doc_URI = new URL( document.baseURI );
  if (this.hash !== "" && buildPath( this ) === buildPath( doc_URI )) {
    // the rest of your code
```